# How to replace string with regex in Java or Clojure

Tags: java, regex, clojure

I have some String like this:

```
"this is a string like #{aa} and#{bb}. "
"#{cc}this is another str#{dd}ing..."
```

I want to change these String like this:

```
"this is a string like ? and?." "aa" "bb"
"?this is another str?ing..." "cc" "dd"
```

I tried to use regular expressions to split these string and failed.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the string using a regex like this:

```
#\{(.*?)\}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/bW9dO6/1)**

Then you have to grab the content from the capturing group and concatenate it to your string. I leave the logic for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
final String regex = "#\\{(.*?)\\}";
final String string = "ere is some string #{sx} and #{sy}.";
final String subst = "?";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print(matcher.group(1) + " ");
}

final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);
System.out.println(result);
```